# How to make sure `has` method of `Map` or `Set` javascript collections compares objects by properties values?

Tags: javascript, collections

I couldn't find more information on this but as far as I understand `has` method from `Map` and `Set` collections determines whether a given map or set has an object by checking for reference equality. But I'd like to check whether the objects are equal by comparing their properties.

For example:

```
let map = new Map();
let obj = {name: "Jack"};
map.set(obj, "myObj");
let result = map.has({name: "Jack"}); //false
```

`result` is false but the properties of the objects are identical, so in such case I'd like `has` to return true.

In Java I'd have to override `equals` and `hashCode` methods inside my class to achieve such functionality. Is there something similar I can do in Javascript without overriding `has` itself?

Comment: You either iterate the Map and compare one by one, or you store JSON strings of the objects, then `has` works as expected.

Comment: @JonasW. thanks, but why is this question a duplicate? I'm asking about internals of `has` not about general comparison of two objects (which the question you linked discusses)

Comment: Jup, `has` uses equality internally, so the answers are the same

Comment: @JonasW. "has uses equality internally" this should be the answer then.

Comment: Why not set map key as a string derived from unique values in the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but the properties of the objects are identical

Really? As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201471/5260024) outlines, it is usually very hard to define the identity of an object, as it is built of much more than sinple key-value pairs. Therefore it is impossible to derive a unique hash for it to be used in a hashtable, thats why javascript uses the object reference in the Hashtables. It also makes sense as you could get collisions otherwise. Additionally, if you change an object that is included in a hashtable so that it equals to another one, what should happen then?

---

Now in a lot of cases, you probably know how the object is built and how you can get its identity. Imagine a player that has a unique username, e.g.:

```
 function Player(username, password) {
   this.username = username;
   this.password = password
 }
```

Now when we want to build a Set to check if an username is already existing, it makes sense to just use the Players username instead of the player itself:

```
 const a = new Player("a", "super secret");
 const b = new Player("b", "****");
 new Set([a.username, b.username]);
```

Or you could define a way to build up a unique key from the players properties:

```
 Player.prototype.identity = function() {
   return this.username + "°" + this.password;
 };
```

So one can do:

```
 const a = new Player("this is", "equal");
 const b = new Player("this is", "equal");
 console.log(
   a === b, // false
   a.identity() === b.identity() // true
 );

 const players = new Set([a.identity()]);
 players.has(b.identity()); // true
```